# Can I mock a superclass's constructor with Mockito/Powermock?

Tags: java, inheritance, mockito, superclass, powermock

Is it possible using Mockito and optionally Powermock to mock a superclass `S` such that any calls to the superclass to `S` (including calls to the `S()` constructor) are mocked?  So using the below example, if I replace `S` with `MockS` using Mockito, will the call to `super()` use the constructor in `MockS`?

```
class S {
   S() {
      // Format user's hard drive, call 911, and initiate self-destruct
   }
}

class T extends S {
   T() {
      super();
   }
}

class Test {
   @Mock private S mockS;
   new T(); // T's call to super() should call the mock, not the destructive S.
}
```

I've seen questions about mocking individual methods in `S` or mocking only calls to `super()`, and read that this is unsupported, but it's not clear whether or not I can mock the entire superclass.

With my current tests, when I try to mock `S`, `T`'s call to `super()` calls the real implementation, not the mock.

Comment: how does your mock call super()? can you provide a code example?

Comment: @nansen I'm not calling `super()` from the mock, the mock is the superclass.  Please see my edits.

Comment: I don't like that class `S` very much.

Comment: @DerMike Why do you think I want to mock it?  I can only call it once. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work around this apparent limitation, I refactored my code, [replacing inheritance with delegation](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceInheritanceWithDelegation.html), and I think I've ended up with a better design anyhow since the inheritance wasn't really necessary.

The new code looks like this.  Mind you the code for the question was simplified, so the real classes have much more functionality.

```
class S {
   S() {
      // Format user's hard drive, call 911, and initiate self-destruct
   }
}

class T {
   T(S s) {} // Now T "has an S" instead of "is an S"
}

class Test {
   @Mock private S mockS;
   new T(s); // T's call to super() should call the mock, not the destructive S.
}
```

For those interested, using Guice and Android, the test looks more like this:

```
class T {
   T(Activity activity, S s) {}
}

class Test {
  @Mock Activity activity;
  @Mock S mockS;
  injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
     @Override protected void configure() {
        bind(Activity.class).toInstance(activity);
        bind(S.class).toInstance(mockS);
     }}
  );
  T t = injector.getInstance(T.class);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to achieve something similar to what has being described here, I am testing this one out but its showing a compile error on BindEverythingElse(), not sure where this class is from, I included the guice-2.0 dependency. Do I need to add any other additional dependency or am I missing something. Thanks!!

Comment: @Rishi if you have no other custom bindings, just eliminate that line.  As a matter of fact, it's irrelevant to the answer, so I am removing it.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is possible with PowerMock only if the method on the child is different from the method on the superclass (i.e., you cannot mock the parent method if the child overrides that method). For a little more detail, you can look at [the  relevant bug report](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=51).

For PowerMock, check out [Suppressing Unwanted Behavior page](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior) to see if it will be enough for your needs.

---

After much digging around, I ended up using [JMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/) for these tricky cases.  Before I moved on to JMockit, I tried stubbing out all the places exceptions were thrown using suppression. In the end, I needed to override some methods, and not just suppress them, so I ended up abandoning it.

Example usage for Android case:

First, you mock out your superclass using the `@MockClass` annotation:

```
@MockClass(realClass = Activity.class, instantiation = PerMockedInstance)
public class FakeActivity {
    public Bundle mSavedInstanceState;

    @Mock
    public void $init() {}

    @Mock
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    }
}
```

When activated, this class will replace the default constructor of `Activity` with `$init()`, and replace the `onCreate` method with the one above. WIth android, the unit under test is derived from Activity (in my sample code, it is `HelloTestActivity`). The test class looks like this:

```
public class HelloTestActivityTest3 extends AndroidTest {
    @Tested
    HelloTestActivity activity;

    FakeActivity fakeActivity = new FakeActivity();

    @Before
    public void setupMocks()
    {
        Mockit.setUpMock(fakeActivity);
    }

    @Test
    public void onCreate_bundle(@Mocked Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Try to access out-of-band information from the fake
        activity.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        assertSame(savedInstanceState, fakeActivity.mSavedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

The call `Mockit.setupMock(fakeActivity)` replaces the super class with my instance of the fake. With this usage, you can access internal state of your fake class as well. If you don't need to override any methods with custom functionality, you can use other methods available from `Mockit` class.

As rogerio pointed out in the comments below, mocking the `Activity` class is the bare minimum. The following code demonstrates this.

```
public class HelloTestActivityTest4 {
    @Tested
    HelloTestActivity activity;

    @Mocked
    Activity base;

    @Test
    public void testOnCreate() throws Exception {
        // Just make sure "Stub!" exception is not thrown.
        activity.onCreate(null);
    }
}
```

The declaration `@Mocked Activity base;` causes all methods (excepting static initializers) of `Activity` class and its superclasses to be mocked in the tests defined in `HelloActivityTest4`.

Comment: This may be my misunderstanding, but I'm talking about mocking the entire superclass, not just one method.  See my edit and let me know.

Comment: I have used JMockit to mock out the "fake" android Activity class where each method throws the exception "Stub!" when called from JVM. You can mock the super out, or replace certain methods with fakes that perform shortcuts and mock the rest out, remove constructors or static initializer blocks, etc. The flexibility is not available in PowerMock. But I will read the modifications, and revise my answer if necessary.

Comment: Are we all using Powermock because of Android?  :)  I've already mocked `Activity` (I inject them with Roboguice and bind `Activity.class` to instance `mockActivity`).  In the case of this SO post, I was testing an extension to `ArrayAdapter` and generalized it to `S` in the question.  To succeed, I ended up replacing inheritance with delegation and then mocking the injected delegate.

Comment: @glenviewjeff I think we do. I'd like to think I wouldn't write smelly code that would require the services of these advanced test frameworks. :) As a matter of curiosity, can Roboguice inject a superclass, or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: So first as an aside, it's Guice itself doing the injection in this case, not the Roboguice part.  And no, I bypassed the call to super by replacing inheritance with delegation, meaning that `T` no longer extends `S` but takes a delegate `S` in its constructor.  And yes, Guice provides this automagically when I bind it.  I'll post an unaccepted self-answer showing what I did.

Comment: Using JMockit's `@Mocked` on the superclass should also work, as it causes the entire class to be mocked by default.

Comment: @Rogerio Thanks for the tip. I needed something a little more, so I didn't even check that. But it should work (you may need to add extra parameters to `Mocked` to get the constructors under control, but I am not sure). The problem with Android is that you don't get away with mocking `Activity` alone. You also need to get rid of all of its supers as well (`Context`, `ContextWapper`, and `ContextThemeWrapper` for the example above). I will experiment a little and report the results here later.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is extract the 'dangerous' code in your superclass constructor into a non-private method, then use Mockito spy on your class T and override the behaviour in that extracted method.

This would of course violate encapsulation. Guava offers the [VisibleForTesting](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) annotation for such cases.

Comment: With PowerMockito you have PowerMockito.whenNew(S.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockedS); This works when you explicitely call new S() but not with super(). Formatted my hard drive ;)

Comment: I ended up replacing inheritance with delegation and then mocking the delegate.