# Does any mocking framework allow spying on a super classes method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, superclass

We are using spring oauth and there are several places where we need to use inheritance.

In the immediate case we are extending TokenEndpoint

```
public class MyTokenEndpoint extends TokenEndpoint {
    //...
    public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> getAccessToken(
            Principal principal,
            MyParams myParams,
            @RequestParam Map<String, String> allParams) {

        // .. Stuff Happens

        updateParamsWithStuff(allParams);

        return super.getAccessToken(
        principal, myParams.grantType(), allParams);
    }
    //...
}
```

Now what I want to test is if the map passed to super.getAcccessToken has been filled with Stuff.  My simple way was to spy on the map passed in, but this relies on implemetation details and does not actually insure that stuff is in the map passed super.getAccessToken

We are using Mockito, I have seen comments that this will not work, and one that implies it may.  Can this be done in any of the mocking frameworks?

See both answers on ( [Can I mock a superclass's constructor with Mockito/Powermock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957102/can-i-mock-a-superclasss-constructor-with-mockito-powermock), the checked one says impossible, but given the discussion on the second answer I just had to try.)

After reading that I tried the following:

```
MyTokenEndpoint spyEndpoint = Mockito.spy(endpoint); //endpoint Set-up previously

Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken>>() {
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> 
           answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
       Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
       Map<String, String> params = (Map<String, String>) args[2];
       System.out.printf("%s\n", params.toString());
       return new ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
}).when(((TokenEndpoint) spyEndpoint))
.getAccessToken(any(Principal.class), 
                anyString(), (Map<String, String>) anyMap());

theResponse = spyEndpoint
                .getAccessToken(principal, 
                                myPrams,
                                currentMap);
```

But the code in answer never gets called.

Am I barking up the wrong tree??  Is this possible in any mocking framework?

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to mock super methods. It would break the polymorphism mechanism java uses. The most powerful mocking library i've used, Powermock, is (as far as I know) incapable of mocking 'super.xxx()' mathods

Comment: Thanks Adam.  I was afraid that would be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to mock?  You are already extending the class--just override that method, examine the data passed in then forward the data to the parent.

Comment: Ok, my mock fu is still developing.. but the calls already has an overridden method with the same signature, that throws an exception if called.  This is why we are calling super.oldMethod.

Answer (score 0):

Such a test can be easily written with [JMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit):

```
@Test
public void mockCallToSuper(@Mocked final TokenEndpoint mockedBase)
{
   final Principal principal = null; // or whatever
   MyParams myParams = new MyParams();
   Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

   ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> accessToken =
      new MyTokenEndpoint().getAccessToken(principal, myParams, params);

   // asserts on "accessToken"

   new Verifications() {{
      Map<String, String> actualParams;
      mockedBase.getAccessToken(
         principal, (MyParams) any, actualParams = withCapture());

      assertEquals("abc", actualParams.get("A"));
      assertEquals("another item", actualParams.get("B2"));
   }};
}
```

Comment: I need to force the return value as well.  I am sending in a mock object to force an exception.  If I cannot capture the call to super I end up needing a mock object that returns a mock object and the test gets messy and brittle fast.

Comment: No problem. To provide a return value for the call to `super.getAccessToken(...)`, you would record an expectation for it with the desired return value assigned to the `result` field.